# Electron-hole symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I am reading a paper which says:

Define the Matsubara Green's functions
\begin{equation}
G_\sigma(\tau-\tau') = -<T\{ d_\sigma(\tau) d_\sigma^\dagger(\tau') \}>
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bar{G}_{\bar{\sigma}}(\tau-\tau') = -<T\{ d_\bar{\sigma}(\tau) d_\bar{\sigma}^\dagger(\tau') \}>
\end{equation}
From the electron-hole symmetry, we have
\begin{equation}
G_\sigma(\tau-\tau') = -\bar{G}_\bar{\sigma}(\tau'-\tau).
\end{equation}

I do not very understand this concept and my questions mainly focus on
1) What's the definition of electron-hole symmetry?
2) How can this definition leads to the above identity?
Thanks in advance.